# Calling method on all instances of class

Tags: php, oop

I am looking for a way to call a function on all instances of a class preferably via a static method call.

Example:

```
class number{

    private $number;

    static function addAll(){
        //add all of the values from each instance together
    }

    function __construct($number){
        $this->number = $number;
    }
}

$one = new number(1);
$five = new number(5);

//Expecting $sum to be 6
$sum = number::addAll();
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Then you probably want a collection of those instances, and put your addAll() method against the collection, because each instance is completely independent of the others otherwise: unless you create a connection via a collection, $one and $five are totally unrelated

Comment: I don't think there's a solid generic way to do this, but you could keep a list(array/collection) of instances and keep that list up to date using the class's constructor and destructor. Then, the static method can iterate through that list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done like this:

```
class MyClass {

    protected $number;

    protected static $instances = array();

    public function __construct($number) {
        // store a reference of every created object
        static::$instances [spl_object_hash($this)]= $this;
        $this->number = $number;
    }


    public function __destruct() {
        // don't forget to remove objects if they are destructed
        unset(static::$instances [spl_object_hash($this)]);
    }


    /**
     * Returns the number. Not necessary here, just because
     * you asked for an object method call in the headline
     * question.
     */
    public function number() {
        return $this->number;
    }


    /**
     * Get's the sum from all instances
     */
    public static function sumAll() {
        $sum = 0;
        // call function for each instance
        foreach(static::$instances as $hash => $i) {
            $sum += $i->number();
        }
        return $sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing important, you could just initialize `$instances` with declaration.

Comment: Don't like that static initialization stuff in PHP too much as it behaves differently in different use cases.. But however, here inline initialization fits.. have changed this.

Comment: I don't like what OP is doing. However, in given context field `$number` is immutable, so there's no need to keep all instances in static array. Just one int will work fine.

Comment: @Leri Replace `private` by `protected` and it would be a good question :)

Comment: @Leri, why not you post an answer which is good and you like it also? Thanks hek2mgl for a nice answer and example code

Comment: @altafhussain 1. I try to avoid answer on questions, that may lead future readers to bad coding practices. 2. No need two, logically the same answers, while I can suggest how existing answer could be improved. :)

Comment: A collection of `number` objects would do it better... This is very inflexible...

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos A collection of number object would be usable only if one software layer is controlling the creation of every number object. Generally this answer is better. I've thought carefully about that before answering. Otherwise you may define *better*

Comment: What is the possibility of you wanting to add EVERY SINGLE NUMBER that was created? Normally, you have to add just a well defined set of numbers.

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos It is part of the question?

Comment: IMO, it should be. Unless he REALLY needs to add all of them, there is no reason for doing like this.